# Tab completion error: "-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device"

Tags: linux, bash

I am getting this tab completion error:

```
-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

I have attached image when I do `df -h`

Please let me know how to fix it because I am stuck on this[image]

Comment: why do you say that it is a tab completion error?

Comment: Welcome! [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: Well your `Use%` of `/dev/sda1` is at 100%

Comment: Because when I write any command I used tab to autocomplete but it is not workinh

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yes I know that but how can I fix it so i can run my program on virtual machine properly.

Answer (score 0):

You run out of space on your root (`/`).

Reading your comment, you are talking about a virtual machine, thus the probably easiest solution is to grow up the virtual hard disk of your VM.

Another solution is to clean your root by removing: unused programs, old logs, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help how can i clean up the unused programs & old logs??

Comment: It depends on the *package manager* the linux distribution (another information missing from the OP...) you have installed is using for